# Disappearing scrollbars in Monotouch UIScrollView

Tags: c#, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I have a UIScrollview, defined in a XIB, and i change its contents like this :

```
foreach(var subview in scrollViewer.Subviews)
{
    subview.RemoveFromSuperview();
}

scrollViewer.AddSubview(newView);

scrollViewer.ContentSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF(newView.Frame.Width, newView.Frame.Height);
```

After i call this code, the scrollviewer's contents are replaced, and i can scroll without a problem (the actual scrolling works just fine), but the scroll bars are gone.

How can i do this, but keep the scrollbars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first subview of a scrollview is an UIImageView that is the scroller at the bottom. To avoid removing that you would skip the first item:

```
foreach(var subview in scrollViewer.Subviews.Skip(1))
{
    subview.RemoveFromSuperview();
}

scrollViewer.AddSubview(newView);

scrollViewer.ContentSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF(newView.Frame.Width, newView.Frame.Height);
```

Comment: Alas, this is not the case.
The content of the UIScrollView scrolls gratuitously, but the scrollbars are still not visible.

Comment: Please see update. In my project, I was iterating backwards and leaving the last item, but the Skip method is more elegant.

Comment: While the you nailed the crux of the issue, (the UIImageView), there is still a problem.
In my tests, i have noticed that the first subview is not always per definition the UIImageView containing the scroll bars (it might also be that your custom view is at position `scrollViewer.Subviews[0]`, and the scroll bars are at position `scrollViewer.Subviews[1]` so be careful when you try this!

Comment: i've fixed that with :

`if(!(subview is UIImageView))
    {
     subview.RemoveFromSuperview();
    }`

Comment: And you'll have to wait a while before i can award the bounty. Take my word on it that i will :)

Comment: Funny, I did the same check initially, but I didn't know if the uiviews you were using were not uiimageviews too. :)

Comment: I should still come up with an alternative for when that is the case. i'll dig around to see if there's an easy way to identify the UIImageView containing the scrollbars.